# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'text'

Tags: jquery, jqtouch, typeerror, zepto

I use the autotitle extension for jQtouch, it stopped working when i updated to Zepto 1.
the extension help to copy the clicked content to the H1 toolbar at the top.

the error message: 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'text'

Here the code

```
(function($) {
if ($.jQTouch)
{
    $.jQTouch.addExtension(function AutoTitles(jQT){

        var titleSelector='.toolbar h1';

        $(function(){
            $('#jqt').bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, data){
                if (data.direction === 'in'){
                    var $title = $(titleSelector, $(e.target));
                    var $ref = $(e.target).data('referrer');
                    if ($title.length && $ref && $title.text() === ''){
                        $title.html($ref.text());
```

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'text'

```
        function setTitleSelector(ts){
            titleSelector=ts;
        }

        return {
            setTitleSelector: setTitleSelector
        };

    });
}
})($);
```

Any idea why it doesn't work anymore?

Comment: i should sleep sometime (-_-)ZZZ

Comment: Do you mean you switched to Zepto from jQuery? I don't see how this code would have ever worked in vanilla Zepto.

Comment: This code work with zepto 0.08 but not with zepto 1.0